# Save pictures of Excel cells into a Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My code pastes a picture of the cells.

It should then paste the other cells which don't fit on the first page.

The picture of the 'second page' does not paste.

```
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object
Dim sFil As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

On Error GoTo 0
Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add  ' create a new document
wdApp.Visible = True
'change sheet and range below
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:z43").CopyPicture xlPrinter
wd.Range.Paste
wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
wdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections (2)
ActiveSheet.Range("a43:z76").CopyPicture xlPicture
wd.Range.Paste

'wd.SaveAs Filename:="I:\'Files\RKG-COMMS\" & URNa & " - " & URNb & ".doc"
'wd.Close
'wd.Quit
```

Here is the result - only the first page
[image]

This is the second page which should be pasted
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using late-bound Word and **not** using Option Explicit, which means you've got empty variables that you don't know are empty because you think they are Word constants :) Without a reference to the Word library, you'll need to declare and assign any needed constants such as `wdSectionBreakNextPage`. Otherwise, they're empty variants.

Comment: Could you please provide screen shots of the actual result and the required result? Please make sure the display of non-printing characters is enabled. Then we can be sure what it is you want. I *think* I understand it from the text (see my edits), but it's not certain... You're not getting any errors, is that correct?

Comment: @DavidZemens unfortunately i have referenced it correctly :(

Comment: @CindyMeister Sorry im new to stack and new to VBA in general Hopfully you can see the results in my edits

Comment: And which part(s) of these two pages are being pasted as pictures from Excel? Then entire page's content?

Comment: @CindyMeister yes all of it

Comment: The entire contents of the word doc is an *image* of text copied from Excel? Two questions: why not just use Word natively as a text editor? If you insist on using Excel, can you export as PDF? The latter seems functionally equivalent if not a bit superior to the current screenshots-in-docx format.

Comment: @DavidZemens the material would be sensitive and thus a password would be used to secure the document so it can be sent over email in regulations of GDPR

Comment: You can secure PDF and DOCX/M with password. So I still don't understand why the need to use Excel as an intermediary.

Comment: @DavidZemens i did not build the system  and thus just adding to it , previously however i believe the company i work for used excel as a basic database before and just kept the system to then automate pension emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult for me to test what you're doing, but logically I believe the following should work, although there may be one problem (keep reading)...

Notice how this code uses a Word `Range` object as the target for new content. After pasting it's uncertain whether `docRange` will be before the pasted content, or contain the pasted content. If it contains the pasted content, the code should work. If it's before the pasted content, then next picture will come in before the first one. In that case, *repeat* the line `Set docRange = wd.Content` immediately after `docRange.Paste`.

```
    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add  ' create a new document
    Dim docRange as Object 'Word.Range
    Set docRange = wd.Content
    wdApp.Visible = True
    'change sheet and range below
    ActiveSheet.Range("a1:z43").CopyPicture xlPrinter
    docRange.Paste
    'Go to the end
    docRange.Collapse 0 'wdCollapseEnd
    docRange.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    ActiveSheet.Range("a43:z76").CopyPicture xlPicture
    docRange.Paste
```

In response to an inquiry in comments about how the code works in detail:

```
Dim docRange as Object 'Word.Range
```

Declares an object variable to hold the part of the document the code works with. Because the code in the question, running from Excel, apparently uses *late-binding* (no reference to the Word object library) it's declared as an `Object`.

If early-binding were being used (the code project has a reference to the Word libraray) then declaring it `As Word.Range` would be preferable. I include the Word object data type (`Word.Range`) for the sake of completeness and to make it possible to research the object and its properties in the Help.

```
Set docRange = wd.Content
```

This *instantiates* the `Word.Range` object to contain the entire main body of the document (`wd` being instantiated in the code in the question to the target Word document).

After pasting, `docRange` still refers to the entire content of the document, including what was pasted. If the section break and second paste action were to be executed immediately, this would *delete* the content of the range. (Think of it like selecting text in Word, then typing: what was selected is replaced by what is typed. In order to avoid this, one presses the right arrow key before typing so that the new content follows what was selected.)

For this reason, the range is "collapsed" (like pressing the arrow key). Then the section break is inserted and the next paste action is executed.

Comment: Dim docRange as Object 'Word.Range
Set docRange = wd.Content - what do these lines do? and then why i would then need to reassign the object to paste the second section of the page